# FMOD error in borland turbo c++ 4.5

Tags: c++, c, audio, turbo-c++, fmod

when I'm trying to compile it gives me 26 errors however everything is at its right place
but won't able to understand the errors mostly constant is too long.
Plz help I want to play a mp3 file through C programming.

*errors are shown in the jpg image

```
 #include "inc/fmod.h"

    FMUSIC_MODULE* handle;

    int main ()
    {
       // init FMOD sound system
       FSOUND_Init (44100, 32, 0);

       // load song
       handle=FMUSIC_LoadSong ("don.mp3");

       // play song only once
       // when you want to play a midi file you have to disable looping
       // BEFORE playing the song else this command has no effect!
       FMUSIC_SetLooping (handle, false);

       // play song
       FMUSIC_PlaySong (handle);

       // wait until the users hits a key to end the app
       while (!_kbhit())
       {
       }

       //clean up
       FMUSIC_FreeSong (handle);
       FSOUND_Close();
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH4Ts.jpg

Comment: Why do I see so many noobs on SO constantly use Turbo C++? Especially when superior compilers, like gcc are free. Beats me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have listed is FMOD 3 code, yet you are using FMOD 4 headers (and probably libs too). This will not work, I can see from your error pic you have other troubles too, perhaps include paths not being set correctly.

We provide a Borland lib that you will need to link with: 'fmodex_bc.lib' but again this is FMOD 4 code, I would highly recommend looking at the 'playstream' example that ships with the SDK, it demonstrates MP3 playback.

Answer (score 3):

Borland Turbo C++ pre-dates most C++ standards and modern C. I would not expect FMOD or any modern library to work with this compiler.

Visual C++ is free to use in the Express form, and is a vastly better compiler.

Comment: Gnu GCC is also free to use in its full glory form, as well ;-)